# How do I read file with content-URI in React Native on Android?

Tags: android, file, react-native, filesystems, file-browser

I'm using React Native (0.48.3) for Android development. It seems, I'm stuck with a really trivial task: select a file and read it's content as a string. I have [react-native-document-picker v2.0.0](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-document-picker) for file selection, and it works fine: I can choose file and get it's URI. The problem is, I cannot make any package to read file with this link. I've already tried [react-native-filesystem](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-filesystem) and [react-native-fs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-fs), but it seems, they can work only with files in application directory. Anyway I get an error like this:

`Error: File was not found: content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/7`

What package or function I need to use?

**UPD:** retrieving real, not `content://` path, with [react-native-get-real-path](https://github.com/Wraptime/react-native-get-real-path) makes things work. But is this conversion really necessary, can one use `content://` path for loading files?

Answer (score 5):

Say you are using `react-native-fs`, using `copyFile` can convert content uri to file uri.

```
if (url.startsWith('content://')) {
    const uriComponents = url.split('/')
    const fileNameAndExtension = urlComponents[uriComponents.length - 1]
    const destPath = `${RNFS.TemporaryDirectoryPath}/${fileNameAndExtension}`
    await RNFS.copyFile(uri, destPath)
}
```

Then you can use `'file://' + destPath` as expected

Comment: what a precious answer!

Comment: What is urlComponents?

Comment: you have to replace % characters

const destPath = `${RNFS.TemporaryDirectoryPath}/${fileNameAndExtension}`.replace(/%/g, "")

Answer (score 2):

There is already merged pull request [#395](https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs/pull/395) in [react-native-fs](https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs) which added a possibility to read from URI starting with `content://` directly. I'm using Android URI in this code without any problem:

```
DocumentPicker.show({ filetype: ['*/*'] }, async (error, res) => {
  ...
  const exportedFileContent = await fs.readFile(res.uri, 'base64')
  ...
})
```

Answer (score 1):

This is 2023 and incase anybody still needs help, you can try the package **react-native-blob-util**

I faced the issue when I used react-native-document-picker to select files. What helped me was using the RNBU.fs.readStream() function. I first used it to convert to base64 then used react-native-fs to save the file to my device directory with the RNFS.writeFile() function. [React Native Blob util](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-blob-util) I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

On Android devices, you will need to append "file://" to load any file. You can do this using the package you mentioned or just manually. If you append it manually, react-native-fs can then be used to read the URI.

Answer (score 0):

**Content URI to absolute path in React native ( ANDROID )**

```
const isInternalStorage = res?.uri.startsWith('content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/primary');
const isSdCardStorage = res?.uri.startsWith('content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/') && !isInternalStorage;
```

to convert the path from content URI to absolute to read file or directory using react-native-fs library

For SD card reading ->

```
const  convertExternalStoragePathToAbsolutePath  = (path: string) => {
let dirToRead = path.split('tree')[1];   
dirToRead = '/storage' + dirToRead.replace(/%3A/g, '%2F');
// console.log("prePath:",path ,"cov: ",dirToRead)
return decodeURIComponent(dirToRead);
}
```

For Internal Storage reading->

```
const convertInternalStoragePathToAbsolutePath =  (path: string) => {
let dirToRead = path?.split('primary')[1];   
const InternalStoragePath =  RNFS.ExternalStorageDirectoryPath;
dirToRead = InternalStoragePath + dirToRead.replace(/%3A/g, '%2F');
// console.log("prePath:",path ,"cov: ",decodeURIComponent(dirToRead))
return decodeURIComponent(dirToRead);
}
```

Results

Sd card ->
From react-native-directory-picker we'll get -

```
ContentURI = content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/777B- 
D380%3ADownload
absolute path = /storage/777B-D380/Download
```

This absolute path can be used with react-native-fs to read files

Internal Storage ->

```
ContentURI= content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/primary%3ADownload%2FMeet
absolute path = /storage/emulated/0/Download/Meet
```

example to read all the videos from a directory

```
 const searchFiles = async (path: string) => { 
 const files = await RNFS.readDir(path);     
const videoFiles = files.filter(file => {
  const fileExtension = file.name.split('.').pop();
  return ['mp4', 'avi', 'mov', 'mkv','ts'].includes(fileExtension ?? '');
  });
  setVideoList(videoFiles);
    // save it inside storage
    storage.save({
      key: 'videoList',
      data: videoFiles,
    }).then(() => {
      console.log("videoList saved successfully");
    
    })
  console.log("Directory changed ");
 }
```